# Bash: How to capture error and echo value at the same time using local variable?

Tags: bash, shell, error-handling, echo, return-value

When I am trying to capture an error in a shellscript, if I use local variable to capture the echo value, the $? capturing the return value will always be 0 even if the function returns 1.

Why is that?

I can use global variable to address the issue, but I guess it violates the standard. Is there a better way to handle the error when I want to capture some echo value?

Thanks!

For example:

When using local variable:

```
test_error_handle() {
    echo "Some text"
    return 1
}
method() {
    local test=$(test_error_handle) # Use local variable
    echo "$?"
    echo ${test}
}
method
```

The output:

```
0
Some text
```

When using global variable:

```
test_error_handle() {
    echo "Some text"
    return 1
}
method() {
    test=$(test_error_handle) # Use local variable
    echo "$?"
    echo ${test}
}
method
```

The output:

```
1
Some text
```

Answer (score 3):

Usually the exit status is the exit status of the last command executed.

```
local test=$(test_error_handle)
```

What happens here is that:

- shell run the command `test_error_handle`
- then shell runs the command `local`
- `local` returns with zero exit status

So when you do `echo $?` you see the exit status of `local` command.

When you do:

```
test=$(test_error_handle)
```

the exit status of this expression is the exit status of the command substitution, that runs `test_error_handle`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
method() {
    local test
    test=$(test_error_handle) # Use local variable
    echo $?
    echo "${test}"
}
```

Keep the declaration on a separate line and the assignment on its own line. Then `$?` should hold the correct value.